# Use postcss-normalize with Svelte

Tags: svelte, postcss

I didn't manage to import [postcss-normalize](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-normalize/) to Svelte using [official starting boileprlate](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.37.0) and [svelte-preprocess](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/).

My rollup config:

```js
…
plugins: [
  svelte({
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
      sourceMap: !production,
      defaults: {
        style: "scss",
      },
      scss: {
        prependData: '@import "sass-mediaqueries/media-queries";',
      },
    }),
    compilerOptions: {
      // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
    },
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        // postcssImport(postcssNormalize().postcssImport({ path: ["src"] })),
        postcssNormalize(),
        autoprefixer(),
      ]
    }
  }),
  // we'll extract any component CSS out into
  // a separate file - better for performance
  css({ output: "bundle.css" }),
  …
```

I import it like this in `App.svelte`:

```html
<style global>
  @import-normalize;
  @import-sanitize;
  @import "global.scss";
</style>
```

No normalize neither sanitize css gets into the bundled `bundle.css`. No errors or warnings.

As you can see in the config above I also tried to import it using [postcss-import](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import) plugin as found in the `postcss-normalize` Github page and Github issues. No luck so far. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to learn SvelteKit.
To add normalize.css to SvelteKit follow the next steps:

1. `$ npm install normalize.css`
2. `$ touch src/routes/__layout.svelte`

In the `__layout.svelte` you must add the following:

```
<script>
  import 'normalize.css'
</script>

<slot/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm i -save-dev sass`
2. `npm i --save sanitize.css`
3. `touch src/routes/__layout.svelte`

Add this to `__layout.svelte`:

```
<style global lang='scss'>
  @import 'sanitize.css';
</style>

<slot/>
```

It works to me in this way (I'm using SvelteKit) - all imported CSS is included to the bundle.

P.S. `sanitize.css` includes `normalize.css` - no need to install them both